# CakePHP create folder in controller? [Need Expert Advice]

Tags: cakephp, controller

How is it possible to have folder in controller?

For example this scenario: We have multiples clients and each clients might have different package that share the common controller or different controller based on their own request. So I was thinking to separate them by directory in the controller.

Any Expert in Architecture can help this?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably possible, but is certainly not the way you should do things with Cake (or MVC in general, probably).

I suggest that you have a separate app for each client. If you have any specific questions regarding this, or would like to add more information to your question about what you're trying to do, I can try to give you a more in-depth answer.

Comment: Thanks but was thinking that multiple apps might be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more it is hard to say.

I assume you have one app that is used by multiple clients through subdomains or something else to make a difference between who is using it.

You can have a plugin per client that extends the base apps controllers as needed. You also can have different models and views then. Use routes to make the different named controllers match always the same URLno matter what client is logged in.

I would prefer a one app solution over multiple applications because it reduces the maintenance overhead a lot. But if you want to for multiple apps I would build the core of the application that is shared by all sites as a plugin itself. Using git and submodules you can then even control what version of the core module each site is using.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick reply. Your described scenario is much similar to what I am looking at(Through subdomains). Can you elaborate more on "You can have a plugin per client that extends the base apps controllers as needed. You also can have different models and views then. Use routes to make the different named controllers match always the same URLno matter what client is logged in." ? Thanks.

Comment: Simple OOP: SomePluginController extends SomeAppLevelController inside of your plugin. Load the plugin conditionally based on the subdomain.